# How to Get All Images of different folders inside Firebase Storage to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have some folder inside the wallpaper folder of `FirebaseStorage`, Each folder contains different images.

I want to show all the images in `RecyclerView`! How can I do that Please help...

Check My `FirebaseStorage` Folders and My Code

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nm97.png)
[Firebase Storage Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ZHE.png)

Comment: Do you have reference provided in your database ?

Comment: Yes, I just want to get all images of each folders...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
StorageReference listRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("wallpaper");
    listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for (StorageReference items : listResult.getPrefixes()) { // for each folders
                items.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                        for (StorageReference items : listResult.getItems()) { // for each files in a folder
                               Log.d("File Name", items.getName());
                               fileList.add(items.getName());
                        }
                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Firebase Storage [Docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files)